# why can a non public class with a route attribute compile webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I built a project with webapi RoutePrefix attributes on a controller class and noticed that I was getting 404 errors when trying to hit the endpoints. Shouldn't the compiler fail to compile with a private class with RoutePrefix attributes or is there a reason why you would want a private class with a RoutePrefix attribute?

```
 [RoutePrefix("joblog")]
    class SplunkController : ApiControllerBase    // class name *must* end with "Controller" or else this will not be picked up for routing!!
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetByID/{environmentInfoId:int}/{jobGuid}")]
        public IEnumerable<JobLog> Splunk_GetById(int environmentInfoId, string jobGuid)
        {
            return new List<JobLog>();
        }
    }
```

This code compiles but will not function as intended because it is missing a public Access Modifier. Based on @Damien_The_Unbeliever comment there is no mechanism for attributes to enforce access modifiers. Perhaps this is the answer... or is there a work around?

Comment: it will be useful for others to  answer, if you share some code related to your question. it will clear the context of your question.

Comment: There's no mechanism in .NET by which attributes would interact with accessibility modifiers.